# D3 Stacked bar graph works in Tributary but nowhere else

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This has the expected results I want but when I import the code into my HTML file as a script it doesn't show anything at all.

```
var PUBLIC = [50,40,10];
var NONPROFIT = [30,40,30];
var FOR_PROFIT = [70,15,15];

var data = [
  {"key":"PUBLIC", "pop1":PUBLIC[0], "pop2":PUBLIC[1], "pop3":PUBLIC[2]},
  {"key":"NONPROFIT", "pop1":NONPROFIT[0], "pop2":NONPROFIT[1], "pop3":NONPROFIT[2]},
  {"key":"FORPROFIT", "pop1":FOR_PROFIT[0], "pop2":FOR_PROFIT[1], "pop3":FOR_PROFIT[2]}
];

var n = 3, // Number of layers
    m = data.length, // Number of samples per layer
    stack = d3.layout.stack(),
    labels = data.map(function(d) { return d.key; }),       
    // Go through each layer (pop1, pop2 etc, that's the range(n) part)
    // then go through each object in data and pull out that objects's population data
    // and put it into an array where x is the index and y is the number
    layers = stack(d3.range(n).map(function(d)
                                   { 
                                     var a = [];
                                     for (var i = 0; i < m; ++i)
                                     {
                                       a[i] = { x: i, y: data[i]['pop' + (d+1)] };  
                                     }
                                     return a;
                                   })),
    // The largest single layer
    yGroupMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y; }); }),
    // The largest stack
    yStackMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; }); });

var margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 50},
    width = 677 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 533 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain(d3.range(m))
.rangeRoundBands([2, height], .08);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, yStackMax])
.range([0, width]);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, n - 1])
.range(["#aad", "#556"]);

var svg = d3.select("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
.data(layers)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "layer")
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });

layer.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.x); })
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.y0); })
.attr("height", y.rangeBand())
.attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.y); });

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.tickSize(1)
.tickPadding(6)
.tickValues(labels)
.orient("left");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis);
```

I believe I have all the required libraries imported and then some:

```
<!-- D3 Library -->
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
<!-- jQuery Mobile -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Main -->
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
```

While the code to get my variables are a bit simplified (i.e. plainly setting my arrays) they are the same format as what is put within the data array.

Furthermore, this example does not work within CodePen either when I import everything that Tributary uses for its base libraries. While, again, this isn't 100% of the code I have going into the creation a much simpler working example on Tributary does not work on CodePen.

D3 has done nothing but kick my butt these past few weeks and I'm in need of some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add the codepen ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the page to be fully loaded or your can put the code before the closing `</body>` tag.

**Solution1:**

```
$(function() {
    //Put your code here;
});
```

**Solution2:**

```
<body>
    <svg></svg>
    <script> 
        //your code here
    </script>
</body>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/ag6p4kkg/

Comment: Ah, so that helped I think but I'm still not getting anything on the page. The console, however, is noting `Unexpected value NaN parsing x attribute.`, `Unexpected value NaN parsing width attribute.`, and `Unexpected value translate(0,NaN) parsing transform attribute.` which I understand to mean it's missing some value but I'm not sure where the code is getting lost.

Comment: http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/kXZgZr Here you are. Since I'm loading an exterior .csv file initially it won't show anything. Is there a better way I can format it for you to look at? I can replace stuff with mock data if you'd like.

Comment: Please use `tickFormat` instead of `tickValues` take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/ag6p4kkg/1/